# Generating a simple list from another list using append

Tags: python, pymysql

From a list like this (*original_list*):

```
[[], (['2313240'], 51.0), (['2313301'], 55.0), (['2313467'], 51.0)]
```

I need create another list (*result_list*) with only the [0] elements (for example the *2313240*), so I'm trying to extract it using:

```
for row in range(1, len(original_list)):
    result_list.append(original_list[row][0][0])
```

But it's result is similar to this:

```
['2313240', '2313301', '2313467']
```

When I actually want to achieve something like this (elements without brackets):

```
[2313240, 2313301, 2313467]
```

And so I'm able to use it as a parameter to a query:

```
   cursor.execute(sql,[result_list])
```

Right now it logs the following error:

> pymysql.err.InternalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1
>   column(s)')

I have no clue how to solve this since I'm begginer in Python.

Comment: You need to convert the string (variable with brackets) into an int. 2 options: `int()` or `eval()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast to `int` before appending the values to the array:

`result_list.append(int(original_list[row][0][0]))`

Answer (score 0):

And in bonus of my comment, a better way to write this uses list comprehension:

```
L1 = [[], (['2313240'], 51.0), (['2313301'], 55.0), (['2313467'], 51.0)]

In[3]:[int(elt[0][0]) for elt in L1 if len(elt) == 2]
Out[3]: [2313240, 2313301, 2313467]
```